# Tea Leaf analytics for an Angular 6 application

Tags: java, node.js, angular, tealeaf

Did anyone implement Tea Leaf analytics for an Angular 6 version application?

I am creating a cookie at node server (app.js) and then expecting to have 
cookie available with each API service call from the Angular application.
Cookie needs to be visible in the HTTP request headers of each API 
call made from Angular application.

Can you please let me know if we can clone the HTTP response 
headers to have cookie persisted with each API service call from Angular 
application?

Here service API resides on IBM Web sphere. Tried placing 
withCredentials: true by cloning the HTTP request headers in 
TestInterceptor file.

```
/* Interceptor code goes here...*/
@Injectable()

export class TestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest < any > ,
    next: HttpHandler): Observable < HttpEvent < any >>
  {    
    req = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json'),
      withCredentials: true
    });

    return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(error => {
      return throwError(error);
    }));
  }
}
```